# How to remove index from array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, indexing

I have following array :

```
Array
(
    [relation] => AND
    [0] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => restaurant_country
                    [value] => India
                    [compare] => ==
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => restaurant_city
                    [value] => East Delhi - Noida
                    [compare] => ==
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => restaurant_price_min
                    [value] => 100
                    [compare] => <=
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => restaurant_price_min
                    [value] => 500
                    [compare] => <=
                )

        )

)
```

I want to remove indexing from the above array. e.g I want the following array instead of above.

```
Array
(
    [relation] => AND
    Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => restaurant_country
                    [value] => India
                    [compare] => ==
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => restaurant_city
                    [value] => East Delhi - Noida
                    [compare] => ==
                )

        )

    Array
        (
            [relation] => OR
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => restaurant_price_min
                    [value] => 100
                    [compare] => <=
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => restaurant_price_min
                    [value] => 500
                    [compare] => <=
                )

        )

)
```

I want array in this format because wordpress query run in this way.

I am not getting how to do this.

Please help me.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is having an array without keys, which is not possible and not needed. The array you already have will work if passed as an argument for a WordPress query.

Comment: No its not working.That's why I asked. the second array works because it is without index

Comment: 2nd array is not without key.1st array and 2nd array is same

Answer (score 2):

The array you want  is simply not possible, because each array has its key, you can't remove it.

Answer (score 1):

It seem's to be a var_export display.
Maybe you are trying to show it with print_r ?

even answer of 3DR is correct, it's impossible..